# How to use default schema privileges on functions in Postgres in right way?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, database-administration, postgresql-10

I am struggling to comprehend how default schema privileges work in Postgres. To me, they are something that supposed to ease administration load by issuing permissions automatically, but I found them bit unusable. I discovered several things that are not at all obvious from [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).

I want several users to be able to create and modify objects in schema. I create a role who gonna be the owner and grant this role to multiple (in general) users:

```
create schema my_schema;
create role my_schema_owner;
alter schema my_schema owner to my_schema_owner;
create user my_user password 'xxx';
grant my_schema_owner to my_user;
create role my_role;
alter default privileges in schema my_schema grant execute on functions to my_role;
create function my_schema.my_func1() returns int as
  $$ begin return 3; end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

Please note that I do this under my own (administration) account.

Next, I check what I got. I use this view:

```
create or replace view pg_functions_grants as
select proname, n.nspname, coalesce(nullif(s[1], ''), 'public') as grantee,
       s[2] as privileges, s[3] as grantor
from pg_proc p
join pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace
join pg_roles r on r.oid = p.proowner
join pg_type rt on p.prorettype = rt.oid,
unnest(coalesce(p.proacl::text[], format('{%s=arwdDxt/%s}', r.rolname, r.rolname)::text[])) acl,
regexp_split_to_array(acl, '=|/') s
```

and request permissions for created objects:

```
select * from pg_functions_grants where proname = 'my_func1' order by 1;

my_func1    my_schema   public      X       <me>
my_func1    my_schema   <me>        X       <me>
my_func1    my_schema   my_role     X       <me>
```

a) We see it granted execute on func1 to PUBLIC. It's OK, documentation says it's by default.
b) It granted execute permission to me. It's OK, but it seems redundant since I am already the owner.
c) It granted execute to my_role as I asked. Perfect.

Now I pretend that I am a user to whom ownership was granted:

```
set role my_user;
create function my_schema.my_func2() returns int as
  $$ begin return 3; end; $$ language plpgsql;

select * from pg_functions_grants where proname = 'my_func2' order by 1;

my_func2    my_schema   my_user     arwdDxt my_user
```

d) Why did not it granted execute to PUBLIC?

e) Why the hell it did not apply default privileges?

I try to figure out what's going on:

```
create or replace view pg_namespaces_default_grants as
select n.nspname, r.rolname, d.defaclobjtype, coalesce(nullif(s[1], ''), 'public') as grantee,
       s[2] as privileges, s[3] as grantor
from pg_default_acl d
join pg_namespace n on d.defaclnamespace = n.oid
join pg_roles r on r.oid = n.nspowner,
unnest(coalesce(d.defaclacl::text[], format('{%s=arwdDxt/%s}', r.rolname, r.rolname)::text[])) acl,
regexp_split_to_array(acl, '=|/') s;

select * from pg_namespaces_default_grants where nspname = 'my_schema';

my_schema   my_schema_owner f   my_role X   <me>
```

Hmmm... I see the grantor mentioned here... May be this is important? Let's set up defaults under my user:

```
set role my_user;
alter default privileges in schema my_schema grant execute on functions to my_role;
create function my_schema.my_func3() returns int as
  $$ begin return 3; end; $$ language plpgsql;

select * from pg_functions_grants where proname = 'my_func3' order by 1;

my_func3    my_schema   public  X   my_user
my_func3    my_schema   my_user X   my_user
my_func3    my_schema   my_role X   my_user
```

Now it worked as expected.

OK, may be it inherits default privileges through granted roles?

```
set role my_schema_owner;
alter default privileges in schema my_schema grant execute on functions to my_role;
set role my_user;
alter default privileges in schema my_schema revoke execute on functions from my_role;
```

Let's verify it:

```
select * from pg_namespaces_default_grants where nspname = 'my_schema';

my_schema   my_schema_owner f   my_role X   my_schema_owner
my_schema   my_schema_owner f   my_role X   <me>
```

Correct. And now:

```
set role my_user;
create function my_schema.my_func7() returns int as
  $$ begin return 3; end; $$ language plpgsql;

select * from pg_functions_grants where proname = 'my_func7' order by 1;

my_func7    my_schema   my_user arwdDxt my_user
```

Damn, it does not!

To conclude: default privileges work only when creating objects under the user (explicit) **who set** the default privileges and does **not** work under users that were granted with role who set default privileges.

Now questions:

1. Is the fact above is mentioned in some place in documentation which I failed to find?
2. Why is it so inconvenient? May be I misuse it? Is there way to set default privileges in schema that would work for every user with some granted role? For all (existing and future) users?
3. It is completely unclear situation with PUBLIC. Why did not it grant EXECUTE to PUBLIC in d)? I conducted few more experiments and discovered that if a user have **any** default grants set for a schema, they get *augmented* by EXECUTE for PUBLIC. But if there are no default privileges no EXECUTEs granted to PUBLIC on functions. It looks completely illogical to me. Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer the questions raised towards the end:

1. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) says:

   > ```
   > ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
   >     [ FOR { ROLE | USER } target_role [, ...] ]
   >     [ IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] ]
   >     abbreviated_grant_or_revoke
   > ```
   >
   > `target_role`
   >
   > The name of an existing role of which the current role is a member. If `FOR ROLE` is omitted, the current role is assumed.

   You always define default privileges *for a certain role*, that is, the privileges only apply when that role creates an object.
2. That's the way it is. The best thing is to have only a single role that is allowed to create objects in a schema.
3. Any granted privileges are added to the existing privileges.

   All functions are created with `EXECUTE` privileges for `PUBLIC`, and I don't believe your result in d). You'll have to come up with a simple reproducible test case for that.

   The only way to change that is to have a default privilege (not restricted to a schema!) that *revokes* the `EXECUTE` privilege.

Comment: Thanks for #1, I misunderstood the concept. In #2 it is very inconvenient to have a single role because it is typical situation when there are several developers working on a project and any of them should be able to add columns, change structure etc.

Comment: As for #3 the simple reproducible test case is as follows: `create schema s; create function s.f() returns int as $$ begin return 1; end; $$ language plpgsql;`. My Postgres `version()` is PostgreSQL 10.3 (Ubuntu 10.3-1.pgdg14.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4, 64-bit

Comment: If several users should be able to create objects in a schema, put them all in a role that has write access to the schema and have them use `SET ROLE` before they create an object. I tried your example with `s.f()`, and `PUBLIC` had the `EXECUTE` privilege as expected.

Comment: I so no way to force them doing it, they are people and will forget about it next day. Revoking INHERIT from their roles will force them to use SET ROLE, but will create loads of other inconveniences. Regarding PUBLIC: what can be wrong with may database? May be some configuration parameters are missing? Some global setting?

Comment: `NOINHERIT` is the right thing. About the permission problem: I cannot think of a setting that would cause this. Maybe you should open a different question with a *complete* test case, including all `CREATE ROLE` and other commands.